# Set span width then clear float

Tags: css

Ok, so I know to set a absolute width for a span you have to set a float. My question is, beings the float is only for setting the width, is there a way to make the css clear the float right after with having to add a bunch of "float: clear;" elements?

I think something like this should be close:

```
#we_gallery_edit_settings .item_title
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.item_title:after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Its not that to set a `absolute width` for a `span` you have to set a `float`. To set a `width` and `height`, element `display` should either be `block` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buLbqvyn/)

If you only want to set the width of the `span` you don't have to make it `float`. Just use `display: inline-block;` and then set the `width`.

#### HTML

```
<div id="we_gallery_edit_settings">
  <span class='item_title'>Name Span</span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#we_gallery_edit_settings .item_title {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that simplified things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using clear: both

```
 .clear {
    clear: both;
  }
```